# Openedge use Windows service name to connect to port

Tags: sockets, windows-services, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to write a program that will test a Linux port to see if it's listening. The program runs on a Windows box and the port number could be variable, depending on the service selected. I'm need to look up the port number using the Windows Service file.
Below is my procedure:

```
define input parameter ip-network-id as char no-undo.
DEFINE VARIABLE hSocket AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cService AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cHostName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lResult AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

CREATE SOCKET hSocket.

GET-KEY-VALUE SECTION "DATABASE" KEY "dbhostname" VALUE cHostName.

ASSIGN
cService = "txipd" + ip-network-id /*ip-network-id = "fis" */
lResult = hSocket:CONNECT("-H " + cHostName + " -S " + cService) NO-ERROR.

IF lResult THEN do:
    MESSAGE cHostName "is accepting Cilent/Server connections on" cService " ."
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.

    /* Once done with the database disconnect and delete the object */
    hSocket:DISCONNECT() NO-ERROR.
    DELETE OBJECT hSocket NO-ERROR.
end.
Else
    MESSAGE "The Database is not listening on this port" cService lResult cHostName
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

My Windows Services file contains the follow entry:

```
txipdfis        31357/tcp
```

ip-network-id could equal one of many options selected from a browse, the service txipdfis might be on a different port number depending on how the particular installation was setup so I need to look for "txipdfis" in the Windows service file to determine the correct port number. Is this possible?

Comment: It ought to work -- if it isn't working are you getting an error message?

Comment: This code works in my environment when I hardcode hostname and service! Perhaps wrong data in the registry or a routing issue, local firewall etc

Comment: Does your entry happen to be the last line in your services file? If so, you may need to add an enter (crlf).

Comment: @StefanDrissen my entry was the last in the services file, I added a CRLF and tested again, still not able to connect.  I don't seem to get any "errors" except the message that says the nothing is listening on the port.
This got me thinking.... what if there's not a database actually listening on that port on the Linux side.  What if it's a program that's listening, would that be an issue?  I'm really only aiming to check that _something_ is listening on that port, not exactly a database.

Comment: @StefanDrissen, on my second attempt after adding the CRLF, I am actually able to connect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows services file did not have a blank line as the last line.  Once I updated the services file with a CRLF at the end, I was able to connect.